# iOS Register for notifications in background

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, push

I need to refresh push token if user don't run app for long time. I tried to use background mode and     application:performFetchWithCompletionHandler:
method. Inside this method I call - registerUserNotificationSettings:(UIUserNotificationSettings *)notificationSettings. And then I expect that didRegisterUserNotificationSettings (UIUserNotificationSettings*)notificationSettings will be called but this not happen. Is there any way to register in APNS without running app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple Answer is No

APNs can issue a new device token for a variety of reasons:

User installs your app on a new device
User restores device from a backup
User reinstalls the operating system
Other system-defined events
**As a result, apps must request the device token at launch time,** as described in APNs-to-Device Connection Trust and Device Tokens. For code examples, see Registering to Receive Remote Notifications.

Apple Documentation : https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/APNSOverview.html